# diophantine equation with power and twice square

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that $x^n=2y^2+3$, $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$, has no solution $(x,y,n)$ in positive integers.

I managed to get $x\equiv3\pmod{8}$ and $y$ is even and $n\equiv7\pmod{8}$. After taking modulo $2$, $x$ has to be odd.

Note that $x\equiv x^n\equiv 2y^2+3\equiv 3,5\pmod{8}.$

Also $x^n-1=2(y^2+1)$, and the odd prime factors of $y^2+1$ are $1\pmod{4}$. If $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $n\equiv x^{n-1}+...+1\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. $\bot$

So $x\equiv 3\pmod{8}$. Then $2y^2+3\equiv x^n\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, so $y$ is even.

Comment: To get proper mod formatting, use \pmod.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan i used $\bot$ as a symbol for contradiction. but guess it was removed.

Comment: The first sentence is an assertion, which you make only if you have proved something. But it doesn't seem like you have proved it, so you shouldn't assert it. As currently written, your "question" has no question. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: May this idea helps:

We use Euler's primes generator $p=2y^2+29$ and rewrite the equation as:

$x^n=2y^2+29-26=p-26$

few numerical test shows this relation can not be hold:

$y=4\rightarrow p=61\rightarrow x^n=61-26=35$

$y=5\rightarrow p=79\rightarrow  x^n=79-26=53$

$y=13\rightarrow p=367\rightarrow  x^n=341$

$y=28\rightarrow p=1597\rightarrow x^n=1571$

Answer (score -1):

COMMENT.-It is not hard to prove that the odd $x\equiv1,5,7\pmod{10}$ and $x\not\equiv3,7,9\pmod{10}$ so if you follow this reduction modulo $10$ you need to prove the impossibility with $n\equiv3\pmod4$ of $$(10x+1)^n=2y^2+3\Rightarrow y\equiv2,3,7,8\pmod{10}\hspace 1cm (1) \\(10x+5)^n=2y^2+3\Rightarrow y\equiv 1,4,6,9\space\space\pmod{10}\hspace 1cm (2)\\(10x+7)^n=2y^2+3\Rightarrow y\equiv5\pmod{10}\hspace 1cm (3)$$ This is a set of nine possible equations to prove be impossible. You must take into account that for exponent $n$ large and not prime, diophantine equations are hard to solve.